# Rails: Undefined Method Error for Namespaced, STI-Inherited Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, namespaces, sti

I have an `after_create` callback in my `Tag` model:

```
def auto_vote
  params = parametrize_media_tag(media_tag)
  Tag::Vote.cast_vote(params)
end
```

Which gives me this error:

```
undefined method `cast_vote' for #<Class:0x7ae7a90>
```

My `Tag::Vote` model is quite simple:

```
class Tag::Vote < Vote

  def self.cast_vote(params)
    Vote.cast_vote_of_type(params, self.class.name)
  end

end
```

Why isn't Rails detecting the `cast_vote` method?

Comment: Are you sure that the file declaring this method is being loaded?

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't be, but perhaps you're right. How could I check to make sure?

Comment: You could simply output something (using `puts` or `Rails.logger`) inside the class definition...

Comment: I loaded the rails console and typed `Tag::Vote.new`, which worked. It seems the model is loading. I do think I've stumbled on the problem, though. If I add a blank `cast_vote` method to the STI model `Vote`, then everything works as expected. Perhaps STI-inheriting sub-classes need their methods mirrored in the parent class?